# Design: How much should a method do?

Tags: java

I understand that a method should effectively serve a single purpose.  But what if my method (also acts as API) is named like execute() ?

So the stuff is like this :

```
void execute() {
    /* some steps to initialize stuff */
    List<String> dataToBeExecuted = mainClass.getData();
    /* initialization ends */

    /* steps to actually execute data */
    for( ...) {
        try {
            /* generate args to be passed to executeData() */
            otherClass.executeData(args.. , dataToBeExecuted);
        } catch {
            /* log stuff */
        }
    }
    /* execution ends */

    /* steps to do some validation */
}
```

Okay, so now this function in itself is doing 3 things,

`* initialize stuff
 * execute Data
 * validate stuff`

It can be broken down into 3 methods, but I think since the logic is simple enough it can be kept in the parent execute() method.

What is the correct approach?

Comment: Even though your logic is simple enough now, it may change tomorrow, so that for example the validate step becomes huge. You may want to split init, execute and validate in 3 methods (maybe which have private visibility if not needed from outside) and create a public one called something more generic (process?) that does all 3 of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a question of whether the logic is simple or not. It's the question of the integrity of data. For example:

- Will the initialize operation leave the data in some state which is exposable? Meaning, is there anything that can happen to the object after initialization that is harmful for execution?
- Does it make sense for the clients of the class to get an object which is initialized but not executed? Or executed but not validated?
- Are there any other operations possible apart from execution on initialized objects? Or queries? Or is execution the only natural thing to happen after initialization?

The answers to questions like this will guide the decision of whether execute is a single public method, or it is split into three. (Of course you can always internally split it into three private methods.)